# Closed form of Baker Campbell Hausdorff theorem with cyclic bracket structure

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, closed-form, noncommutative-algebra

I would like to know if there exists a closed form of the Baker Campbell Hausdorff theorem subject to the conditions that $[x,[x,y]] \sim x$ and $[y,[x,y]] \sim y$.

The simple cases that I know a closed form exists are when $[x,y]$ is a scalar, then the expansion truncates as 
$\log(e^x e^y) = x + y + \frac{1}{2}[x,y]$ 
and if $[x,y] = sy$ for some constant $s$, then we have
$\log(e^x e^y) = x + \frac{sy}{1-e^{-s}}$.

These lead me to believe that there should be some closed form since I know the higher order terms in the BCH expansion are proportional to $x$ and $y$.

My specific problem is trying to apply these with $x = a \frac{d^2}{dp^2} $ and $y = b p^2$ for some (possibly complex) constants $a$ and $b$. 
The commutator is 
$[x,y] = ab(4 p \frac{d}{dp} + 2)$
The nested commutators are 
$[x,[x,y]] = 8a^2b\frac{d^2}{dp^2}$ and
$[y,[x,y]] = -8ab^2p^2 $.

Indeed these are proportional to the original x and y. Is there a known closed form of the BCH theorem for this example? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related to [1378098](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378098/question-related-to-the-campbell-baker-hausdorff-formula). Indeed, *x+y* and *x-y* take you to that problem, so *su(2)*, whose entire [composition law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#The_group_composition_law_of_SU.282.29) is well known, derived in the faithful doublet representation, the Pauli matrices. Your operators are standard in string theory and CFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with a realization of *su(2)*, standard in CFT and stringery.

Define 
$$
\sigma_x=i(x+y)\\
\sigma_y=x-y\\
\sigma_z=-[x,y]/(4ab),
$$
so that 
$$
    \left[\sigma_x, \sigma_y\right] = 2i\sigma_z \, \\
    \left[\sigma_y, \sigma_z\right] = 2i\sigma_x \, \\
    \left[\sigma_z, \sigma_x\right] = 2i\sigma_y  ~,
$$ 
recognizable as the commutation relations of *su(2)*, realized by the faithful representation of the [Pauli 2x2 matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices),
$$
\begin{align}
   \sigma_x &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
 \sigma_y &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&-i\\
      i&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  \sigma_z &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
    \end{pmatrix} \,.
\end{align}
$$

Because they are so easy to manipulate and exponentiate, they serve to instantly produce the [generic composition law of group elements of the group *SU(2)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#The_group_composition_law_of_SU.282.29),
$$
\begin{align}
  e^{i a(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma})} e^{i b(\hat{m} \cdot \vec{\sigma})}
    =& I(\cos a \cos b - \hat{n} \cdot\hat{m} \sin a \sin b) \\
&+ i(\hat{n} \sin a \cos b + \hat{m}  \sin b \cos a - \hat{n}\times\hat{m} ~ \sin a \sin b  )\cdot  \vec{\sigma } \\
    =& I\cos{c} + i (\hat{k} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin{c} \\
    =& e^{i c \left(\hat{k} \cdot \vec{\sigma}\right)},
\end{align}
$$
where the basic spherical law of cosines, $\cos c = \cos a \cos b - \hat{n} \cdot\hat{m} \sin a \sin b~$ yields *c*, so that 
$$\hat{k} = \frac{1}{\sin c}\left(\hat{n} \sin a \cos b + \hat{m} \sin b \cos a - \hat{n}\times\hat{m}  \sin a \sin b\right) ~. $$

You only need carefully normalize the coefficients (angles) and unit vectors involved in arbitrary expressions you'd like to CBH-compose.

Since these are group identities, the combinatorics is identical for any faithful representation, so you obtained the answer in the 2x2 Pauli matrix one, but it will also, then, mutatis mutandis, hold for your differential operators.

Comment: I know this is many years later, but aren't you using the fact that $\sigma_i^2=1$ when deriving the composition law of group elements of $SU(2)$? Which doesn't need to hold for a generic representation of the $su(2)$ algebra.

Comment: ***No*** ! You are missing something truly fundamental. (Gilmore's books explain it best, in my view).  The bottom line is a group identity, and not in the universal enveloping algebra! It you are using a faithful representation like this one, all of its commutators in the CBH identity are the *same* as those in any other faithful representation, and, indeed, the abstract algebra! The combinatorics are the same, if you pretend you sum the expansion in the combined exponent. Again, you *never*  use the normalization if you are discussing ground or algebra identities, like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So the statement is that even though the intermediate steps used the fact that $\sigma_i^2=1$, the result should be obtainable using only commutation relationships and thus should hold more generally. Is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely, *yes* ! You may imagine the generic exponent of the CBH formula, where all the nested commutators result in a vector in the Lie algebra, *identical* for all representations. It is one of the most useful shortcuts in physics!