# Zassenhaus formula for arbitrary (faithful) representation of SU(2)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

In [Closed form of Baker Campbell Hausdorff theorem with cyclic bracket structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699432/closed-form-of-baker-campbell-hausdorff-theorem-with-cyclic-bracket-structure) a BCH formula is given which works for an arbitrary faithful representation of SU(2). Now, is there an equivalent relation for the Zassenhaus formula?

More explicitly, can you write $\exp(it \hat n \cdot \vec\sigma)$ as a product of exponentials of the Pauli matrices? As argued in the linked post, this would give a relation that works for any faithful representation of SU(2).

Comment: Sounds like you're just asking for an extrinsic Euler angle decomposition of versors.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Euler angle formalism; can you maybe give a reference for such a decomposition?

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_angles_to_quaternion_conversion) (see also the links therein), and unit norm quaternions are iso to $SU(2)$. That at least all rotations ($SO(3)$) are a chain of three _intrinsic_ rotations is clear from [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#/media/File:Euler2a.gif). All details (made bothersome by Euler angles being so practical and thus resources often not being for $SU$) is more work and a full answer might include an algorithm computing angles from a standard rep.